# RSA encryption in Android

Tags: java, android, encryption, rsa

I am writing a program which employs RSA in Android. I have the following problem: 
I am getting the RSA keys:

```
KeyPair kp = kpg.genKeyPair();
publicKey = kp.getPublic();
privateKey = kp.getPrivate();
```

Using the encryption function to encrypt a test string:

```
String test ="test";
byte[] testbytes = test.getBytes();
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, publicKey);
byte[] cipherData = cipher.doFinal(testbytes);
String s = new String(cipherData);
Log.d("testbytes after encryption",s);
```

In the decryption function i am decrypting the data back to get the original string

```
Cipher cipher2 = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
cipher2.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, privateKey);
byte[] plainData = cipher.doFinal(cipherData);
String p  = new String(plainData);
Log.d("decrypted data is:",p);
```

The data in 'p' printed out in the log does not match the original string "test" . Where am I going wrong in this?

Comment: Well what is printed out in the log? If you had mismatching keys or garbled cipher you would get an exception, not an incorrect answer.

Comment: Also note that `cipherData` will be a random-like binary string, so converting it to a String by just using the raw bytes (`String s = new String(cipherData);`) may give you strange results.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here an example on how to do it, **BUT** in practice,

> You can't really encrypt and decrypt whole files with  just RSA.  The
>   RSA algorithm can only encrypt a single block,  and it is rather slow
>   for doing a whole file.
>   You can encrypt the file using
>   3DES or AES,  and then encrypt the AES key using intended recipient's
>   RSA public key.

Some code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    KeyPairGenerator kpg = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding");

    kpg.initialize(1024);
    KeyPair keyPair = kpg.generateKeyPair();
    PrivateKey privKey = keyPair.getPrivate();
    PublicKey pubKey = keyPair.getPublic();

    // Encrypt
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, pubKey);

    String test = "My test string";
    String ciphertextFile = "ciphertextRSA.txt";
    InputStream fis = new ByteArrayInputStream(test.getBytes("UTF-8"));

    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(ciphertextFile);
    CipherOutputStream cos = new CipherOutputStream(fos, cipher);

    byte[] block = new byte[32];
    int i;
    while ((i = fis.read(block)) != -1) {
        cos.write(block, 0, i);
    }
    cos.close();

    // Decrypt
    String cleartextAgainFile = "cleartextAgainRSA.txt";

    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, privKey);

    fis = new FileInputStream(ciphertextFile);
    CipherInputStream cis = new CipherInputStream(fis, cipher);
    fos = new FileOutputStream(cleartextAgainFile);

    while ((i = cis.read(block)) != -1) {
        fos.write(block, 0, i);
    }
    fos.close();
}
```

Comment: u have mentioned `You can encrypt the file using 3DES or AES, and then encrypt the AES key using intended recipient's RSA public key.` I needed exactly that to encrypt and decrypt video files. Can you help me with it...some sample will be useful

Comment: @nish i have same requirement , are you able to do that ?